# Change emmet's leader key in Vim

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugin, emmet

Is it possible to to change the way you expand emmet code into HTML?

The default is ctrl+y+, and thats about two too many keys for my liking.

In sublime I just enter the emmet code and hit tab and it expands it. Is there a way to have it do this vim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:help emmet-customize` explains how to customize Emmet's mappings. As a "noob", you owe it to yourself to get used to Vim's documentation.

You could add the line below to `~/.vimr/after/ftplugin/html.vim`:

```
inoremap <buffer> <tab> <plug>(emmet-expand-abbr)
```

However, Emmet has a lot of features accessible via a number of mappings all using the same "leader", `<C-y>` so I'm not sure it is a good idea to take the direction you want to take.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately :help emmet-customize gives me 'Sorry no help for emmet-customize' so I will have to look into that as well.  You are probably right about it being a bad idea it just seems like a really awkward chord to do regularly

Answer (score 10):

Add the expand key-binding below in emmet to your `.vimrc`. You can use both <kbd><Tab></kbd> and <kbd><C-Y></kbd> to trigger emmet. More information can be found in the docs (`:help emmet`).

```
let g:user_emmet_expandabbr_key = '<Tab>'
```

Comment: It is a expand key-binding in emmet, and you can use both `<Tab>` and `<C-Y>` to trigger the emmet. more information you can find in the doc of vim-emmet(tab the `:help emmet` in your vim).

Comment: Thank you for that explanation.   It would be better to edit it into your answer rather than leaving an additional comment.

Answer (score 1):

I added to my configuration the following mapping

```
imap ,, <C-y>,
```

So for example, if I type `div` or any other emmet expression, then I just type `,,` and it gets completed.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using `let g:user_emmet_leader_key='<A-e>'`

use some special key (`<C-e>`, `<A-e>`...) or vim will wait for a emmet-vim command every time you type , or \