# Wierd behaviour on clicking ctrl-y in termux-linux

Tags: ctrl, termux-linux

So basically i use emmet and coc-completions as a neovim developer in termux (it's an android app that runs linux environment). Today all of the sudden, my ctrl-y button started taking 2-3 sec to even execute. Lemme elaborate what i mean .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naNIv.jpg)
Whenever i click ctrl-y, a big "Y" letter comes on the screen and stays for 2 seconds. Which earlier didn't show up and it literally used to take half a second or less. I recall so many things i did before this happened, i am not sure what made it happened. If you have any idea please any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change emmet's leader key in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033849/change-emmets-leader-key-in-vim)

Comment: No it didn't, what that answer is telling is changing your key map to tab and use tab to do your stuff. But i actually want to why is this thing even occuring and how do you fix the problem

Comment: no, the link is saying that CTRL+Y has a special meaning, and can be changed (to, for example, tab)

Comment: Hey so i did what was told, and now ctrl-y is working fine but now tab has got the issue of delaying. Lemme try using the editor if i don't find any problem, I'll consider the question answered. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically what i did is i changed the mapping of emmet code writer to tab from "". The problem now arises with tab, but i don't care as "" is working. Thanks to the guy who helped me :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).